# WSO2 API Manager : API Creation Issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I installed the APIM and started the APIM and created a new API. The ApI which i created comprises of a URL which points at our company production server. I gave the URL  in the api creation mode to the production endpoint and sandbox Endpoint boxes. Then i set the required parameters under the GET method. Then i try it out at the store but the request does not hit the production server. I want to see the URL output from your api manager which passes to our production server. Because i want to see what is whether there is an error on that as it it doesnot hit our production server.

Can you help me with the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable wire log to see the what are the requests which came to APIM and what are the requests APIM made for backend. Follow the steps in [How to get wire logs from WSO2 ESB blog post](http://suhan-opensource.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-get-wire-logs-from-wso2-esb.html) to enable wire log. Those instructions are given for ESB, but they are valid for APIM as well.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I did the commenting out part and  restart the server.  how can i navigate to find the wire logs now?

Comment: They are in <APIM_HOME>/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log file.